# Convert each String in ListBox1 to Integer and add to ListBox2: Incorrectly formatted input string

Tags: vb.net

I have one TextBox, two ListBoxes and two Buttons. The first Button separates each String in the TextBox and adds them one by one to ListBox1. The second Button converts each String in to an Integer. But I get an exception thrown by the debugger:

> Incorrectly formatted input string.

```
System.FormatException was unhandled
HResult=-2146233033
Message=Cadeia de caracteres de entrada com formato incorrecto.
Source=mscorlib
StackTrace:
   em System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, 
NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   em System.Number.ParseDecimal(String value, NumberStyles options, 
NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   em System.Convert.ToDecimal(String value)
   em g_.Form2.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) em 
C:\Users\Utilizador\Documents\Visual Studio 
2012\Projects\g+\g+\Form2.vb:line 17
```

I have inserted code to clean the empty spaces but it continues to throw the same error.
After to reflecting to the problem i have decide to change the way to do it

This is my code:

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim frequency
    Dim interval
    Dim textconverted

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myArray() As Char
        myArray = Me.TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray
        For Each chr As Char In Me.TextBox1.Text
            ListBox1.Items.Add(chr)
        Next
        For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(i)) = String.Empty Then
                ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If (ListBox1.Items(i).ToString.Contains("a")) Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add("1") 'Indexing is zero-based
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: One or more of your strings is not convertible to an integer (a point,  a space, a letter) Use the debugger to find.

Comment: @Steve tank you for have kind to replay well i have try but i go to edit to post the exception trow by the debugger

Comment: @Steve i have insert a break point and its trow me this https://imgur.com/a/CfizA

Comment: @Steve i have also edit my code and inserted the code to clean my empty spaces but it continue to give me the same error

Comment: If you look at the value of the variable _i_ you will see that is "t". This is not something that you can convert to an integer. (or decimal) What is the content of the textbox that you have put char by char in the first listbox?

Comment: @Steve well the idea is insert the strings of textbox in to listbox1 separated one by one and then convert them in to numbers and add to listbox 2

Comment: @Steve after to refleting on the problem i have decide to change the way to do it by detecting if a listbox1 contains a string the insert a number in to listbox2 i go edit and post the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i find a different way to do it and its do what i need.

This is the working solution
    Public Class Form2
    Dim frequency
    Dim interval
    Dim textconverted

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myArray() As Char
    myArray = Me.TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray
    For Each chr As Char In Me.TextBox1.Text
        ListBox1.Items.Add(chr)
    Next
    For i As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If ListBox1.GetItemText(ListBox1.Items(i)) = String.Empty Then
            ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim myVariable As String = "foo"
    For x As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
        If ListBox1.Items(x) = "a" Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add("1")
        End If
        If ListBox1.Items(x) = "b" Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add("2")
        End If
        If ListBox1.Items(x) = "c" Then
            ListBox2.Items.Add("3")
        End If
    Next



End Sub
End Class
```

But now i have other problem with it it only check one string
How can i verify multiple strings there?

Answer (score 0):

I added .ToString to your button 2 code and it worked fine. Turn on Option Strict; you will avoid some runtime errors. I have posted code that will handle a-z instead of a bunch of if statements. Add .ToLower to your TextBox1.Text.ToLower  myArray is never used neither is myVariable.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            For x As Integer = 0 To ListBox3.Items.Count - 1
                Dim s As String = (Asc(ListBox3.Items(x).ToString) - 96).ToString
                ListBox2.Items.Add(s)
            Next
End Sub
```